# Pagination with if statement date modify

Tags: datetime, pagination

How can I incorporate the date_modify into the craft.entries query so that the pagination takes into account this criteria? At the moment the limit is also accounting for past entries and I'm hitting errors whatever I try.

```
{% paginate craft.entries.section('events').limit(10).order('date asc') as entries %}

    {% for entry in entries if entry.date > now|date_modify('-1 day')  %}

        ...

    {% endfor %}


    {% include "includes/_pagination" %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add it like every other criteria property

```
craft.entries.date('>' ~ now|date_modify('-1 day')|atom)
```